# ClassNotFoundException when sending job through RestClusterClient

Tags: scala, apache-flink, maven-assembly-plugin, fatjar

I have a flink job that runs fine when I upload it manually to my cluster (using the UI).

But when I try deploying it via the RestClusterClient, it fails giving me a ClassNotFoundException (I do see the job appear on the cluster, and failing).

```
val packagedProgram = new PackagedProgram(
    new File("/home/laurent/Projects/lead-job-runner/target/lead-0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar"),
    Array("--kafka-bootstrap-servers", "kafka:29092"): _*   
)
val configuration = new Configuration()  
configuration.setString(JobManagerOptions.ADDRESS, "localhost")  
configuration.setString("jobmanager.rpc.port", "6123")

val clusterClient = new RestClusterClient[StandaloneClusterId](
    configuration,
    StandaloneClusterId.getInstance()
)  
clusterClient.run(packagedProgram, 2)
```

Here are the logs from the jobmanager:

```
org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Could not instantiate outputs in order.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getOutEdgesInOrder(StreamConfig.java:398)
    at  org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.createRecordWriters(StreamTask.java:1164)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:190)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.TwoInputStreamTask.<init>(TwoInputStreamTask.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor11.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.loadAndInstantiateInvokable(Task.java:1405)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:689)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: eu.euranova.chng.PlanBuilder$$anon$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.librarycache.FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders.java:129)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil$ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(InstantiationUtil.java:78)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1868)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1751)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2042)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1975)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1567)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2287)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2211)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:797)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor17.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1170)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2178)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2069)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1573)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:431)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:552)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:540)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:501)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getOutEdgesInOrder(StreamConfig.java:395)
    ... 10 more
```

The class in question is indeed not packages in the jar (it is a scala anonymous function class).
[image]

But then... why does the job run fine when launched manually compared to the RestClusterClient, using the exact same fat jar?

Also, when setting flink log level to DEBUG, I see a lot of logs in IntelliJ like this one:

```
DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator     - Transforming TwoInputTransformation{id=17, name='process-control-operator', outputType=Java Tuple2<scala.Tuple2(_1: String, _2: String), GenericType<eu.euranova.model.ShareEvent>>, parallelism=2}
DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph              - CO-TASK: 17
DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator     - Transforming SideOutputTransformation{id=21, name='SideOutput', outputType=Java Tuple2<scala.Tuple2(_1: String, _2: String), GenericType<eu.euranova.flink.streaming.control.event.ControlEvent>>, parallelism=2}
DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator     - Transforming TwoInputTransformation{id=20, name='process-control-operator', outputType=Java Tuple2<scala.Tuple2(_1: String, _2: String), GenericType<eu.euranova.model.Row>>, parallelism=2}
DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator     - Transforming TwoInputTransformation{id=19, name='Co-Map', outputType=Java Tuple2<scala.Tuple2(_1: String, _2: String), GenericType<eu.euranova.model.Row>>, parallelism=2}
DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator     - Transforming PartitionTransformation{id=12, name='Partition', outputType=Java Tuple2<scala.Tuple2(_1: String, _2: String), eu.euranova.model.InstallEvent(userId: String, gameId: String, timestamp: Long, name: String, dumVar: Long)>, parallelism=2}
DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph              - CO-TASK: 19
DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph              - CO-TASK: 20
DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator     - Transforming SideOutputTransformation{id=24, name='SideOutput', outputType=Java Tuple2<scala.Tuple2(_1: String, _2: String), GenericType<eu.euranova.flink.streaming.control.event.ControlEvent>>, parallelism=2}
DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraphGenerator     - Transforming TwoInputTransformation{id=23, name='process-control-operator', outputType=Java Tuple2<scala.Tuple2(_1: String, _2: String), GenericType<eu.euranova.model.Row>>, parallelism=2}
DEBUG org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph              - CO-TASK: 23
```

... this seems to indicate that at least the "driver" is running local, while the tasks are sent to the cluster (other explanation would be that the cluster sends all logs back to the RestClusterClient, which I find unlinkely)

Would you have any idea what is causing this and how could I make it work?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best Regards,

Laurent.

Comment: With "launched manually", are you referring to running the job in IntelliJ?

Comment: For programmatically submitting a jar I would suggest to first upload the jar (see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/monitoring/rest_api.html#jars-upload) and then issue a separate run call (see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/monitoring/rest_api.html#jars-jarid-run). The PackagedProgram class (and related classes) are mostly internal and years old, with unspecified assumption baked in. Alternatively, you could try PackagedProgramUtils#createJobGraph, and submit that instead using RestClusterClient#submitJob(JobGraph).

Comment: Thanks Chesnay, that's indeed what I did: a FlinkClient class that calls the REST API to upload jar, run job, cancel job & delete jar